# administer user in AWS Cognito

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

How can I administer (delete) a user in AWS Cognito in my backend (using Node)?

In this steps, is just user logged (user need to be logged): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

Have this one too (but I dont know the endpoint to use): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html

Do you know another way or how can use this APIReference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `adminDeleteUser` method to delete a user using [JavaScript SDK in NodeJS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminDeleteUser-property).

Note: Make sure you provide necessary IAM policies for the IAM user or role which executives the code.